# Custom User Controls and Events c#

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

I am building a windows Forms application using c# , I build many custom user controls and my GUI is combination of these users controls , the problem is when I set an event for this user controls from the main form , the event does not fire , but if I set that event from the controls it self and set the event handler for all items inside this control to that event handler it works fine , and as much I have wrapped controls I should go deeply to set the events and event handlers , actually this will cost more overhead "Which I don't want it".
ex:

In main form I have control with he name "Patient" which is user control..
if I set the click event for this control from the main form it will not fire

But if I go to the patient user control definition and I define custom event and event handler everything is fine

```
public event EventHandler PatientCliecked;

private void PatientClicked()
{
    if (this.PatientCliecked != null)
    this.PatientCliecked(new object(), new EventArgs());
}

private void ProcessPatientClickedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PatientClicked();
}
```

My question is, is there any other way to do that or this is the logic of .NET ??

Comment: `if I set the click event for this control from the main form it will not fire` ---> Could you make this clearer? How do you do that, any code?

Comment: So in order to avoid name unicity violation within a class you've actually named the event `PatientCli**e**cked` ? That's a no no because people will become nausiated and seasick. You should use English language suffixes or prefixes, something like: `event EventHandler PatientClicked` as opposed to `private void RaisePatientClicked()`

Comment: in the main form for instance :
   `Patient MyPatient = new Patient();
    MtPatient.click += PatientClickHandler;
    private void PatientClichHandler(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
      // Code
     }`
@EduardDumitru .. My problem is not in the names and I don't have any conflict with them

Comment: Who is calling the `ProcessPatientClickedEvent` method ? That is a key aspect of your problem and without this information we can't guess the real issue you're facing. And please confirm I got this right: You would like to completely skip the lines of C# code which are written in you question's body ? Did I get it right ?

Comment: ProcessPatientClickedEvent will be called by the individual controls with Patient user control consist of , for instance if I have a button on Patient user controls the click event handler for this button is ProcessPatientClickedEvent method , what I am facing is if I don't implement the event and event handler in the Patient user control and I set the click event handler for each individual controls in the Patient user controls it will not fire , and if I set the click event handler for the whole control from the main form it will not fire. why the click event not firing by it self ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UserControl inherits the Click event from the Control class.  It certainly can fire, but that isn't terribly likely to happen.  Your user is going to click on the controls inside the UserControl instead.  And it will never fire when you've covered the entire UserControl surface with other controls.

You can simply redirect the Click event for your own use.  Something you've already experimented with by declaring your own event.  That isn't necessary, you can do it like this instead:

```
private void PatientClicked()
{
    OnClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Which, like all methods whose name start with On and have the same name as an event, raises the Click event.

Comment: that what happen exactly .. I think it is .net fault because the click event is still considered as event for the individual control not for the whole user control. but you need to re implement the event and its handlers in the user controls class.

Comment: The ability to redefine an event with a single line of code is a feature, not a fault.

Comment: what I mean by fault is they don't consider the whole user control :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and give it shot.

Say we have a `UserControl`. Say it looks something like this:

[image]

Now, imagine you wrote the following `Click` handlers for the 4 distinct controls which are present (the `Button`, the `ListView`, the `RadioButton` and the `UserControl` itself):

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {

    public UserControl1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void radioButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("RadioButton");
    }
    private void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("ListView");
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Button");
    }
    private void UserControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("UserControl");
    }

}
```

Just to clarify what I'm saying, check this subset of the `.designer.cs` file:

```
...
this.radioButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton1_Click);
...
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
...
this.listView1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_Click);
...
this.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.UserControl1_Click);
...
```

Consider the following affirmations.

When you click on this blue area:

[image]

the `UserControl1_Click` handler will get called and you'll see the "UserControl" message box appear.

When you click on this other blue area:

[image]

the 'listView1_Click' handler will get called and you'll see the "ListView" message box appear **BUT** you won't see the "UserControl" message box.

That is true for both remaining controls, the button:

[image]

and the radiobutton:

[image]

When you're looking at your `UserControl` from its final container's perspective and you see the `Click` event, and you're adding an event handler for it, you should expect the very same behaviour as the that of the `UserControl1_Click` event handler presented here.

If you wish, you can create a custom event handler for any particular set of child controls and simply redirect subscriptions and unsubscriptions to and from that event for whatever handlers the outside world might have:

```
public event EventHandler SmallButtonsClick {
    add {
        this.radioButton1.Click += value;
        this.button1.Click += value;
    }
    remove {
        this.radioButton1.Click -= value;
        this.button1.Click -= value;
    }
}

public event EventHandler LargeStuffClick {
    add {
        this.listView1.Click += value;
    }
    remove {
        this.listView1.Click -= value;
    }
}
```

or even subscribe handler in a dynamical way to every child control *PLUS* the UserControl itself:

```
public event EventHandler AnythingClick {
    add {
        this.Click += value;
        foreach (var child in this.Controls)
            child.Click += value;
    }
    remove {
        this.Click -= value;
        foreach (var child in this.Controls)
            child.Click -= value;
    }
}
```

and then just use that from the surrounding world:

```
UserControl1 someControl = new UserControl1();
someControl.AnythingClick += (sender, e) => MessageBox.ShowMessage("tadaaa!");
```